# Moving from x64 to ARM missing libiomp5.dylib file

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, arm, torch

After fixing most of the dependency issues after moving over, I can't find a way to fix this issue

`Error: Library not loaded: u/loader_path /../../functorch/.dylibs/libiomp5.dylibtorch/lib/../../functorch/.dylibs/libiomp5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libiomp5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libiomp5.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)`

Anyone know how it can be fixed?

I was trying to install tensorflow in my arm python interpreter